# Insert values in a vector of int sets in C++

Tags: c++, vector, set, stdset

I want to insert values into a `vector` of `set<int>`, which is defined using `typedef` as given below:

```
typedef std::set<int> blockSet_t;
std::vector<blockSet_t>* myvector
```

I want to have values such that `myvector[0]` has a `set` of `int`s, `myvector[1]` has a different `set` of `int`s and so on.

Currently, I am passing this `vector` to a function which is parsing a file that has the `set` of integers.

Like:

```
main()
{
 std::vector<blockSet_t> myvector;
 filereader(myvector);
}
```

I read the `set` from the file and store it in a different `blockSet_t  myset;`

I am using the following loop to store this `set` to a specific location in the `vector`:

```
filereader(&myvector)
{
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
 {
  myvector.push_back(myset); // It does not give error but I don't know myset is stored in which location
//what I want is to have someting like this

  myvector[i].push_back(myset); //so I can store different sets at different locations
 }
}
```

I also could not figure out, how to display the values from within the`vector`.

Since it is a vector of `set`s, I want to display each `set` (on a different `vector` index).

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Given a set, you want to push that set into a vector of sets? You also want to be able to iterate through that same vector and print each element in each set? Is that your question?

Comment: Why use a `vector` then? Why not use a dynamic array of `set`s?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `push_back` function is called `push_back` because it pushes an object back.

It means that, if your `vector` is empty and you call `push_back` your pushed object will have `0` location.

If your `vector` has `n` objects inside it, this means after `push_back` your pushed object will have `n`-th index.

```
myvector.push_back(myset);
std::cout<<"index of myset is "<<myvector.size()-1<<std::endl;
```

Secondly, if you want to print values, you have to create your own `operator<<` overloading function for `std::ostream` class. This is a common way of printing values in C++.

Assume you want to print `set` in curly `{}` brakets and vector in square `[]` ones:

```
#include <ostream>

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os,const blockSet_t &mySet)
{
    os<<"{ ";
    for(const auto &value:mySet)
    {
        os<<value<<' ';
    }
    os<<"};
    return os;
}

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os,const std::vector<blockSet_t> &myvector)
{
    os<<"[ ";
    for(const auto &mySet:myvector)
    {
        os<<mySet<<' ';
    }
    os<<"];
    return os;
}
```

Next, you have to `cout` your object like this:

```
#include <ostream>

main()
{
    std::vector<blockSet_t> myvector;
    filereader(myvector);
    std::cout<<myvector<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, So when I push_back myvector.push_back(myset1), if my vector is empty the myse1t goes to 0 location. and when I do myvector.push_back(myset2) again it goes to 1 location right? Now when I display the Size of each set using something like , for(int i=0;i<noofsets;i++)
 {
  std::cout<<"set "<<i<<"is of Size = "<<myvector[i].size()<<std::endl; }  , The sizes I get are not correct. I don't know why.

Comment: @SyedAftabRashid give me your code. Or contact me using skype fnc1234 and we will solve your problem